# How can I passing parameters to action via form without render it in front-end

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is the model:

```
public class UserModel()
{
   public string UserName{get;set;}
   public string UserPassword{get;set;}
   public string UserSource{get;set;}
}
```

Here is the front-end:

```
@model Sample.Models.UserModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

    <form asp-controller="Login" asp-action="LoginIn.html" method="post">
                <div>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="UserName" placeholder="Your username" />
                <div>
                    <h3>Password</h3>
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserPassword"></span>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="UserPassword" placeholder="Your password" type="tel" />
                <button type="submit">Login in</button>
            </form>
```

The front-end is a Partial View. It is referenced like this:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Contact/LoginIn.cshtml", new Sample.Models.UserModel() { UserSource = "From website" })
```

And here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("LoginIn.html")]
        public IActionResult LoginIn(Sample.Models.UserModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            return Redirect();
        }
```

Well, when the form submitted, the controller only can get the `UserName`/`UserPassword` but can't get the `UserSource` unless I add a

```
<input asp-for="UserSource" />
```

into front-end.

I don't want to show the `UserSource` to the user in the front-end(even hide it by CSS).

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Since you are using forms, you would have to use the `hidden` attribute in the `input` tag. Otherwise, if you want to pass it along in the HTTP request another way (such as headers) but you'd have to provide more information in your question.

Comment: @Svek The way you provided is similar like hide it by CSS(it still can be found in the source code of front-end). As you said, it seems I can not achieve this with form but the header can, right?

Comment: No matter what path you pick, you will likely need to send it in the HTTP Request message. Which means, you could pass it along in other areas (i.e. not the body) of the request (such as query string, path, header, etc.). It might be a bit more overhead to do something in the body, but that's also possible, too.

Comment: @Svek All right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to post form,here is a demo:

TestFormAction:

```
public IActionResult TestForm() {
            UserModel u= new UserModel { UserSource = "111" };
            return View(u);
        }
```

LoginController:

```
public IActionResult Index()

    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Login/LoginIn.html")]
    public IActionResult LoginIn(UserModel u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

TestForm.cshtml:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <div>
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
    </div>
    <input asp-for="UserName" placeholder="Your username" />
    <div>
        <h3>Password</h3>
        <span asp-validation-for="UserPassword"></span>
    </div>
    <input asp-for="UserPassword" placeholder="Your password" type="tel" />
    <button type="submit">Login in</button>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();    // avoid to execute actual form submit.
            var model = {};
            model.UserName = $("#UserName").val();
            model.UserPassword = $("#UserPassword").val();
            model.UserSource =@Model.UserSource;
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LoginIn.html", "Login")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: model,
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": token },
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = "/Login/Index";
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

}
```

result:
[image]